# JSP cant find bean Class using "" modifiers

Tags: java, servlets, ejb-3.0, javabeans

Hey I'm using Netbeans for my IDE and I'm getting an error when I try to run my EJB program. I get an error when I declare and give the path of the class in my JSP to a bean.

```
<jsp:useBean id="book" class="BookBean.Book" scope="application" />
<jsp:setProperty name="book" property="*" />
```

When I run the program I get this error

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   class BookBean.Book :
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
>   Class java.beans.Beans can not access
>   a member of class BookBean.Book with
>   modifiers ""

and

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: class BookBean.Book : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.beans.Beans can not access a member of class BookBean.Book with modifiers ""
```

I removed the "" and put in '' to see if that works, but it doesn't. Any idea?
I also put a breakpoint there and it def. is the root of the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. My constructor was not public....

Answer (score 0):

Your class `BookBean.Book` needs to have a `public` parameterless constructor. My guess is that your constructor has no access modifier and is thus package private.