# Invocation target exception

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

Here is code of my program

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class JAdapterOkno extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class CalcButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    Kontroler k;

    CalcButton(Kontroler k, String nazwa, int s) {
        super(nazwa);
        this.k = k;
        setFocusable(false);
        this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, s));
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent er) {
        k.dopisz(this);
    }
}

class InfoButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    Kontroler k;

    InfoButton(Kontroler k, int s) {
        super("Info");
        this.k = k;
        setFocusable(false);
        addActionListener(this);
        this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, s));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent err) {
        k.info();
    }
}

class ClearButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    Kontroler k;

    ClearButton(Kontroler k, int s) {
        super("C");
        this.k = k;
        setFocusable(false);
        addActionListener(this);
        this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, s));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent errr) {
        k.clear();
    }
}

class Wyswietlacz extends JTextPane implements KeyListener {

    Kontroler z;

    Wyswietlacz(Kontroler zz, int k) {
        super();
        z = zz;
        setFocusable(true);
        setEditable(false);
        this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, k));
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if (c == '0' || c == '1') {
            if (z.LorP) {
                if (z.Lwyr.length() < 16) {
                    z.Lwyr.append(c);
                }
            } else {
                if (z.Pwyr.length() < 16) {
                    z.Pwyr.append(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (z.sign == '2' && c != '=' && z.Lwyr.length() != 0) {
                z.LorP = false;
                z.sign = c;
            }
            if (z.sign != '2' && c == '=') {
                z.eval(true);
            }
        }
        z.eval(false);
        StringBuilder fin = new StringBuilder(z.Lwyr);
        if (z.sign != '2') {
            fin.append(z.sign);
            fin.append(z.Pwyr);
        }
        setText(fin.toString());
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        ;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
        ;
    }
}

public class Kontroler extends JApplet {

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    /**
     * < Zmienna menubar
     */
    JMenu menu;
    /**
     * < zmienna menu
     */
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    /**
     * < zmienna element menu
     */
    StringBuilder Lwyr;
    /**
     * < zmienna lewe wyrazenie obliczenia
     */
    StringBuilder Pwyr;
    /**
     * < zmienna prawe wyrazenie obliczenia
     */
    final int modulo = (int) Math.pow(2.0, 15.0);
    /**
     * < stala
     */
    char sign;
    /**
     * < dzialanie
     */
    Boolean LorP;
    int x;
    int y;
    CalcButton inf;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton zero;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton one;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton add;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton sub;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton div;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton mlt;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    CalcButton modu;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    ClearButton blank;
    /**
     * < przycisk gui
     */
    Wyswietlacz wys;
    /**
     * < wyswietlacz
     */
    JPanel przyciski;
    /**
     * < panel guzikow
     */
    JPanel calosc;

    /**
     * < panel
     */
    /**
     * metoda inicjalizujaca applet
     */
    public void st() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("informacje");
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Info");
        menuItem.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                info();
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(menuItem);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        float xx = x / 240;
        float yy = y / 320;
        int avg = (int) ((xx + yy) / 2);
        System.out.println(modulo);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));
        inf = new CalcButton(this, "=", 15 * avg);
        zero = new CalcButton(this, "0", 15 * avg);
        one = new CalcButton(this, "1", 15 * avg);
        add = new CalcButton(this, "+", 15 * avg);
        sub = new CalcButton(this, "-", 15 * avg);
        div = new CalcButton(this, "/", 15 * avg);
        mlt = new CalcButton(this, "*", 15 * avg);
        modu = new CalcButton(this, "%", 15 * avg);
        blank = new ClearButton(this, 20 * avg);
        wys = new Wyswietlacz(this, 15 * avg);
        wys.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, (int) (y / 4)));
        przyciski = new JPanel();
        przyciski.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, x));
        przyciski.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        przyciski.add(zero);
        przyciski.add(one);
        przyciski.add(add);
        przyciski.add(sub);
        przyciski.add(mlt);
        przyciski.add(div);
        przyciski.add(modu);
        przyciski.add(inf);
        przyciski.add(blank);
        przyciski.setFocusable(false);
        calosc = new JPanel();
        calosc.setLayout(new BoxLayout(calosc, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        calosc.add(wys);
        calosc.add(przyciski);
        calosc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));
        calosc.setFocusable(false);
        add(calosc);
        setFocusable(false);
    }

    public void init() {
        st();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        ;
    }

    public void stop() {
        ;
    }

    Kontroler() {
        this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.Pwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.sign = '2';
        this.LorP = true;
        this.x = 240;
        this.y = 320;

    }

    Kontroler(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 240 || y < 320) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Program nie dziala przy tak malej wielkosci okna");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.Pwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.sign = '2';
        this.LorP = true;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void info() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Calc v1.1");
    }

    void dopisz(CalcButton c) {
        String actual = c.getText();
        char ac = actual.charAt(0);
        if (ac == '0' || ac == '1') {
            if (LorP) {
                if (Lwyr.length() < 16) {
                    Lwyr.append(ac);
                }
            } else {
                if (Pwyr.length() < 16) {
                    Pwyr.append(ac);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (sign == '2' && ac != '=' && Lwyr.length() != 0) {
                LorP = false;
                sign = ac;
            }
            if (sign != '2' && ac == '=') {
                eval(true);
            }
        }
        eval(false);
        StringBuilder fin = new StringBuilder(Lwyr);
        if (sign != '2') {
            fin.append(sign);
            fin.append(Pwyr);
        }
        c.k.wys.setText(fin.toString());
    }

    void clear() {
        this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.Pwyr = new StringBuilder();
        this.wys.setText("");
    }

    void eval(Boolean t) {
        int l;
        int p;
        if (Lwyr.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (t || (Lwyr.length() == 16 && Pwyr.length() == 16 && sign != '2')) {
            if (Pwyr.length() == 0) {
                Pwyr = Lwyr;
            }
            l = Integer.parseInt(Integer.valueOf(this.Lwyr.toString(), 2).toString());
            p = Integer.parseInt(Integer.valueOf(this.Pwyr.toString(), 2).toString());
            if (l == 0 && p == 0) {
                Lwyr = new StringBuilder();
                Pwyr = new StringBuilder();
                sign = '2';
                this.LorP = true;
            }
            switch (this.sign) {
                case '+':
                    this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString((l + p) % modulo, 2));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString((l - p) % modulo, 2));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString((l * p) % modulo, 2));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString((l / p) % modulo, 2));
                    break;
                case '%':
                    this.Lwyr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString((l % p) % modulo, 2));
                    break;
            }
            Pwyr = new StringBuilder();
            sign = '2';
            this.LorP = true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Metoda main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Kontroler k;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            k = new Kontroler();
            f.add(k);
            k.init();
        } else {
            k = new Kontroler(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            f.add(k);
            k.init();
        }
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Here is full exception

```
basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
    Class com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1 can not
        access a member of class Kontroler with modifiers ""
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
    Class com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1 can not
        access a member of class Kontroler with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

When I run in "normally", it works; but when I try to run it as applet in web browsers, I recive invocation target exception? where is my mistake? I actually can't see where exception starts because I don't have any details in Java console

Comment: That's way too much code to read. 1) Trim down the unnecessary code 2) Follow Java naming conventions 3) Use english to write source code 4) Post the exception and the line where it happens. Btw Invocation exception have a cause exception which is usually much more interesting. Post both and indicate in your code where they are thrown.

Comment: Could you post the Exception?
It's hard to find an error is such long code sample in a not english language without a specific stacktrace.

Comment: how can i get whole exception from java console in web browers?

Comment: I found answer here [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035879/jsp-cant-find-bean-class-using-modifiers
sorry for double question

Comment: +1 for a _complete_ example that could be _much_ [shorter](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the exception, `IllegalAccessException`, prompts a quick review of [*What Applets Can and Cannot Do*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html), but your applet doesn't *appear* to violate the sandbox.

Running with `appletviewer`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7455066/230513), shows the following error, resolved by making the `Kontroler` constructors `public`.

```
load: Kontroler is not public or has no public constructor.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.applet.AppletPanel can not
    access a member of class Kontroler with modifiers ""
...
```

In addition,

- Use [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), illustrated [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel).
- Consider alternate ways to *construct* a hybrid applet/application, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).
- Consider alternate ways to *deploy* a hybrid applet/application, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
- Don't use [`setPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).